# docker api ssh-agent socket forward

Tags: docker, api, sdk, mount

I am running a docker setup on some host, thats the version information:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.13
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        4484c46d9d
 Built:             Wed Sep 16 17:02:55 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.13
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       4484c46d9d
  Built:            Wed Sep 16 17:01:25 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
 containerd:
  Version:          1.3.7
  GitCommit:        8fba4e9a7d01810a393d5d25a3621dc101981175
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

and there is a experimental feature titled "Using SSH to access private data in builds", link to documentation:

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds

and here it says that this feature is available with api version 1.39+:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options

so i activated the buildkit in the daemon.json file with

```
{ "features": { "buildkit": true } }
```

thats the daemon running:

```
/usr/bin/dockerd --config-file=/etc/docker/daemon.json --experimental -H tcp://*.*.*.*:2375 -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

then i tried to build a docker image via api call:

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/x-tar" --data-binary '@Dockerfile.tar.gz' http://*.*.*.*:2375/build?t=build_test
```

and what do i get back:

`{"message":"Dockerfile parse error line 3: Unknown flag: mount"}`

my Dockerfile looks like this (just a part of it):

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM php:7.2 as composer
RUN --mount=type=ssh mkdir /workdir/
```

Can someone confirm this or give me a hint on this?

Just to clarify, this issue is restricted to the docker api - the buildkit is activated and all works fine on cli!

From what i understand about the code, it's not implemented in the api, my assumption is that because of missing support in python itself, the python docker sdk doesn't support it (https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/2230) and thats why the api doesn't support it yet, propably only python clients out there, using the api :-)

Comment: The output of "docker info" shows "expertimental: false". Looks like the --experimental command line option is not effective on your setup. If you're using systemctl, you might need to restart the docker.service.

Comment: doesn't matter if the client is supporting experimental features, engine does - not even engine needs to, for this feature

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, it's helpful to turn on debugging to see what the CLI is sending. You can also see that it's sending version=2 in the POST /build request, which is required for buildkit. It will then be able to parse the "mount" parameter.

But, more importantly, to confirm your assumption, you'll also see POST /session in the debug output, which is where the secrets are being passed through GRPC.